# While asking the brand

Tags: questions

> 1)What is the brand of your phone?
>
> It is XYZ.
>
> 2)What brand does your phone have?
>
> I have a phone with the brand XYZ or
>
> My phone has the brand XYZ.

Which conversation would be correct while talking about the brand of phone ? I wonder especilally if the second one correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, the second sounds wrong.  Phones *are* one brand or another, they don't *have* brands.

The first is fine, although a native would more likely say: "What brand is your phone?"